# Postgresql trigger doesn't work correctly when it update two rows at the same time

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-update

I am having a problem with trigger on postgresql.

I have tables with tasks and orders. When tasks are updated not at the same time trigger is working correctly, but not when it is happened simultaneously (when two rows updated).

How trigger works.

1. Some user updates the task
2. If there all tasks are done, order will be updated, and will be set as completed.

But in this case, trigger won't be able to see if the all tasks are checked, because of the triggering at the same time.

Trigger definition and function.

```
CREATE TRIGGER "after_update_task_workshop_trigger" AFTER INSERT OR
UPDATE ON "system"."task_workshop"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE "system"."after_update_task_workshop"();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "system"."after_update_task_workshop"()
  RETURNS "pg_catalog"."trigger" AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    ord "system".order;
    count_in_run integer;
    stage "system".stage_workshop;
    stage_old "system".stage_workshop;
    stage_cooked "system".stage_order;
BEGIN
    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
        SELECT *
        INTO stage
        FROM "system"."stage_workshop"
        WHERE keyword = NEW.stage_workshop AND
                id_type = NEW.id_type_workshop;
        SELECT *
        INTO stage_old
        FROM "system"."stage_workshop"
        WHERE keyword = OLD.stage_workshop AND
                id_type = OLD.id_type_workshop;
        IF (stage_old.keyword IS NOT NULL AND stage_old.sort > stage.sort) THEN
            RAISE 'Incorrect taks statuses sequence';
        END IF;
    END IF;

    IF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE' AND OLD.stage_workshop = 'canceled') THEN
        RAISE 'Can`t change status of canceled task';
    END IF;

    IF (NEW.id_product_order IS NOT NULL and NEW.stage_workshop = 'cooked') THEN
        IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM "system".task_workshop WHERE id_order = NEW.id_order AND id_type_workshop = 3 AND stage_workshop NOT IN ('cooked', 'baking'))) THEN
            RAISE 'Not all products have status baking';
        ELSE
            UPDATE "system".task_workshop SET stage_workshop = 'cooked' WHERE id_order = NEW.id_order AND id_type_workshop = 3  AND stage_workshop = 'baking';
        END IF;
    END IF;

    SELECT * INTO ord FROM "system".order where id = NEW.id_order;
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count_in_run FROM "system".task_workshop WHERE id_order = NEW.id_order AND stage_workshop != 'cooked';
    SELECT * INTO stage_cooked FROM "system".stage_order where keyword = 'cooked';

    IF (NEW.id_type_workshop != 3 AND NEW.stage_workshop = 'cooked' ) THEN
        PERFORM "system".print_task(NEW.id);
    END IF;

    IF count_in_run = 0 and ord.stage_keyword != 'collected' and ord.stage_keyword != 'in_delivery' and ord.stage_keyword != 'passed' and ord.stage_keyword != 'canceled' and ord.stage_keyword != 'ended' THEN
        UPDATE "system".order SET id_stage = stage_cooked.id WHERE id = NEW.id_order;
    END IF;
    INSERT INTO "system".status_task_workshop (stage_workshop, id_task_workshop, time, id_type_workshop) VALUES (NEW.stage_workshop, NEW.id, now(), NEW.id_type_workshop);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the  full code of trigger function and the trigger definition [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Yes, you can't solve this problem with triggers unless you serialize the transations, for example with an advisory lock. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/explicit-locking.html

Comment: I suppose I should use FOR UPDATE construction in this case. Am I right?

Comment: I hope your actual code is not like that as `CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER...
DECLARE ...` will not work. The trigger needs to call a separate function. What is the full `CREATE TRIGGER` definition?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver added trigger definition and function. But this doensn't change the perception, cause the error was in select.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name added trigger definition and function